# angularjs directive how to call jquery function from scope watch?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

i am using directive in angularjs and jquery slider function 
i have included slider function on onload  is fine. after i update my array slider images not calling jquery only show images..

Directive Code:

```
sampleApp.directive("imagedata", function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E", 
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.value, function(newValue) {  
                element.html("<img src=./img/"+newValue.name+">");
                      $(".owl-demo").owlCarousel({
                        autoPlay: 3000,
                        items : 6,
                        itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
                        itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3],
                        itemsTablet: [900,3], //2 items between 600 and 0
                        itemsMobile :[1800,6]
                      });

                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

index.html page:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".owl-demo").owlCarousel({
       autoPlay: 3000,
       items : 6,
       itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
       itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3],
       itemsTablet: [900,3], //2 items between 600 and 0
       itemsMobile :[1800,6]
      });
});
</script>



 <div class="col-md-9" ng-controller="AddOrderController">
    <button ng-click="demo()">Update</button>       
     <div class="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel" ng-repeat="a in datas">    
           <div class="item"  ng-repeat="d in a.item track by $index">
              <imagedata value="d"></imagedata>
              </div> 
           </div>
        </div>
```

onload slider function working fine. i am doing new slider image upate used scope watch  only image showing coundn't call slider function..

Comment: why you placed watch on each `ng-repeat` scope variable?

Comment: because. i push another set of 8 image item in array..

Comment: sure i can, but could you please create a fiddle/ plunkr ?

Comment: I think I know whats wrong... In directive before `$(".owl-demo")` put an alert and tell me is it firing on the event when you push more images???

Comment: @AliArshad   no not fire on $(".owl-demo")  this . but   onload its fine